# .bashrc: shopt: not found

Tags: bashrc, ubuntu-12.04

Just provisioned a new Rackspace instance with Ubuntu 12.04 and pulled down rbenv from their github and installed it.

I'm getting the following errors when executing `. ./~bashrc`

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
sh: 18: /home/deployer/.bashrc: shopt: not found
sh: 26: /home/deployer/.bashrc: shopt: not found
sh: 110: /home/deployer/.bashrc: shopt: not found
sh: 28: /etc/bash_completion: [[: not found
sh: 34: /etc/bash_completion: [[: not found
sh: 51: /etc/bash_completion: Bad substitution
```

Here is my .bashrc (for user deployer), the only thing I added was the rbenv bit at the top.

```
$ cat .bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

if [ -d "${RBENV_ROOT}" ]; then
  export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

Update:

Tests asked for in comments:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh
$  /bin/sh -c 'echo $SHELL'
/bin/sh
$ cat /proc/$$/cmdline
sh
```

Comment: Are you actually running bash as your shell?

Comment: Agree with @womble. Even the error messages say `sh`. What does `cat /proc/$$/cmdline` show?

Comment: Or even `echo $SHELL`...

Comment: I find that's not always accurate (may depend on one's rc files). From bash, try `/bin/sh -c 'echo $SHELL'` -- for me that returns "/bin/bash" even though my /bin/sh is a symlink to dash.

Comment: @glennjackman I added the results of those commands in the question. All seem to point sh. How can I get bash?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The output you just posted indicates that you aren't actually running `bash`. This is why you are getting errors sourcing `.bashrc`.

To fix this problem, you need to check your login shell to make sure it's actually set to bash:

```
chsh -l
```

will list the available shells, and

```
chsh -s /path/to/bash
```

will change your login shell to bash.

Then logout and log back in.

Comment: `chsh -l` gives `chsh: invalid option -- 'l'`

Comment: well I checked on root for the path (`/bin/bash`) and it's all good now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oops, it looks like Debian based systems don't use the standard `chsh` from util-linux, but some special and extremely limited custom `chsh` command. On such a system, `cat /etc/shells` instead.

Answer (score 2):

`shopt` is a bash builtin, not a standalone executable, so `source` won't work.  That's why you're getting that error.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I didn't write that part. I just need to add the first couple of executable lines about RBENV so that it can run in non-interactive mode (since the `[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`) will stop that from happening

Comment: Also by source I am doing `. ~/.bashrc`, will fix in question

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when you source your `bashrc` file from other shells (like zsh).
Make sure this line is not present in your current shell's rc file

`source ~/.bashrc`

To check current shell, execute:

`echo $SHELL`

Comment: there is in my opinion no new information posted in this answer, which wasn't already in other answers, to a 6 year old question.